# Setting HTML option to selected on document.ready

Tags: jquery, html

Im having problems with trying to set a select option to "selected", it does not seem to work

**jquery**

```
<script>
   $(function(){
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $("select[name=searchType] option[value=title]").attr("selected", "selected");
       });
   });
</script>
```

**html markup**

```
<select name="searchType">
   <option value="isbn">ISBN</option>
   <option value="title">Title</option>
   <option value="author">Author</option>
</select>
```

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: what browser, it's working for me in chrome/ie10?
http://jsfiddle.net/AqS58/

Comment: This should work http://jsfiddle.net/Bs6jR/ Are you sure jQuery is loaded correctly?

Comment: I tested your code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bcPHL/ it works.

Comment: @CristiPufu im using the latest version of chrom

Comment: @undefined it shouldn't be an issue, I have the following in the header `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`

Comment: will u open the console f12, refresh the page and check for errors ?

Comment: Works fine, I'd also just suggest to use `.prop("selected", true);` http://jsbin.com/utuyiw/2/edit

Comment: I think is not necessary use jquery for this. If you render the option with the attribute "selected" you will give the result you need.

Comment: Ok it seems that another part of my jquery script is causing a problem, i'll have to investigate. thanks guys

Comment: Is the wrapping `$(function(){})` something necessary or commonly used?

Comment: ok it appears a variable in the script was set to `var filter = "a12';` when it should have been set to `var filter = "a12";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('select[name="searchType"] option[value="title"]').prop('selected', true);
```

also, check if your selector returns the element

```
console.log($('select[name="searchType"] option[value="title"]'));
```

Comment: stated already in the comments. the OP's question works really fine. He's not properly adding the jQ library. or else

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `selected` attribute directly in markup:

```
<select name="searchType">
   <option value="isbn">ISBN</option>
   <option value="title" selected="selected">Title</option>
   <option value="author">Author</option>
</select>
```